# Capture error message with status 400 Bad Request VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

When the response is a 400 Bad Request status, I don't know how to capture the message that generates the error.

In postman you can see the error message in the following image:

[image: Capture Message Postman]

My code in vb.net is the following:

```
Dim resp As HttpWebResponse
Dim request As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("MyUrl")
request.Method = "POST"
request.ContentType = "application/json"
request.Headers.Add("authorization", "Bearer " + TokenAPI)
Dim PostString As String = JSON
Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PostString)
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
Dim dataStream1 As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
dataStream1.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
dataStream1.Close() 'sends request
Try
  resp = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
  If resp.StatusCode = 201 Then
      MsgBox("OK")
  End If
  Return "ok"
Catch ex As WebException
    Dim rep As HttpWebResponse = ex.Response
    Return "error"
End Try
```

When the exception is executed in VB.net, the 400 error is detected but I cannot capture the message. View image:

[image: Message Exception VB.Net]

> Capture the message when the response is status 400 Bad Request

Comment: think you want to look at the response stream object.  Should contain the same message details as what you've got in postman https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebresponse.getresponsestream?view=net-7.0

Comment: You have to verify that `ex.Response` is not null or disposed, then read `[WebResponse].StatusDescription` and `[WebResponse].StatusCode` -- Your code is malformed in more than one part. E.g., you should have `Dim request As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp("MyUrl")`, the HttpWebResponse is disposable, the Try / Catch block does not exactly include all that needs to be included etc.

Comment: The [WebResponse].StatusDescription method only shows error 400 same as ex.reponse, but what I need to capture is the error message in JSON format that it shows in the postman, please see image)

Comment: If **the Server** returns a JSON response, then if the WebResponse is not null, you can read the response Stream

Comment: Thank you very much, here I leave the solution, it will surely serve all of you.

Comment: We don't put 'Solved' in the title here.  Put your answer in the Answer box, not in the question.

Comment: Can you please stop putting the answer in the post?  There is an Answer box below where you should place that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's in the response stream

```vb
Catch ex As WebException
    Dim rep As HttpWebResponse = ex.Response
    Using rdr As New StreamReader(rep.GetResponseStream())
        Return rdr.ReadToEnd()
    End Using
End Try
```